# well ordered set on dictionary order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

### Question

> A set $S$ together with partial order $\ll$ is called a well order if it has no infinite descending chains, i.e. there is no infinite sequence $x_1, x_2,\ldots$ of elements from $S$ such that $x_{i+1} \ll x_i$ and $x_{i+1} \neq x_i$ for all $i$.

Consider the set of all words (finite sequence of letters $a - z$), denoted by $W$, in dictionary order.

1. Between $``aa"$ and $``az"$ there are only $24$ words.
2. Between $``aa"$ and $``az"$ there are only $2^{24}$ words.
3. $W$ is not a partial order.
4. $W$ is a partial order but not a well order.
5. $W$ is a well order.

This Question was asked in one of the entrance examination.I found this question interesting , so i tried solving this but got stuck.

### My Approach

Partial order set or POSET is a binary relation having following properties-:

1. Reflexive
2. Antisymmetric
3. Transitive

Now coming to option , it can be easily predicted that there are infinitely many words between $aa$ and $az$.
so option $1$,2$ gets eliminated.

dictionary order are POSET see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Now i have doubt in option $4$ and $5$
Some says that answer will be $5$ because well order is POSET [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)

but from the question i think it will be $4$ because there are  **infinite chains** in lexicographic(dictionary) order. so it will not be well order(according to definition in question)

Please help

Comment: 5 would fail if it is a poset but not a well order.  That is possible.  Some posets are well orders, and some posets are not well orders.

Comment: @GEdgar sir so , am i right that $4$ will be true as it contains infinite sequence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every well order is a total, hence partial order, but the converse does not hold. $(W,\ll)$ is a counterexample, just like you suspected.

And yes, we have infinite chains. We start at some specific, finite word. For example "aab". We could go on with "aaba", "aabaa" etc. but that would mean $x_i \ll x_{i+1}$. However, if we take "aaab", "aaaab" etc. we can see that $x_{i+1} \ll x_i$.

Note that you can use either of these two sequences to show (1) and (2) are false, since all words of both sequences are between "aa" and "az".

Comment: So $4$ will be right ?

Comment: @laura that is correct

Comment: thanks a lot :)